# I'm trying to upload my App for Android TV and the Google team rejects me

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

The Google team responds with the following

> #### No full-size app banner
>
> Your app does not contain a full-size app banner or is it not visible in the launcher. We are targeting 1080P, which we consider xhdpi. Apps should include the banner in the xhdpi (320 dpi) drawables folder with a size of (320px × 180px). Please refer to our Home Screen Banner and UI Patterns documentation.
>
> The title should help users identify apps in the launcher. Please refer to our Visual Design and User Interaction documentation for more information.
>
> For example, your banner does not fill the entire banner space.

The app is developed with ionic 4, how could I solve this inconvenience?

Comment: Upload a correct size app banner and it will work !

Comment: I do not know how to do it in ionic

Comment: Hi, am facing same issue.
using 320px × 180px size, app name showing on banner, image format .webp, banner includes in xhdpi(320 dpi)

Answer (score -1):

Please go through this link
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#banner
Update your manifest file accordingly. You need the mentioned size of banner image.The banner should be an xhdpi resource with a size of 320 x 180 px.

> Text must be included in the image. If your app is available in more
>   than one language, you must provide separate versions of the banner
>   with text for each supported language.

Comment: I do not know how to add that image to the resources with ionic. Do you have any idea how to do it? forgive me the ignorance